# How to test connectivity to external resources in production?

Tags: python, testing, github-actions

I'm building a ETL project that ingests CSV files from a cloud provider and writes data to an external database.

Let's say I have a single test in my test suite: a test that tries to connect to the database.

Is it wise to try to connect to the real database? How can I setup my CI/CD (I'm using Github Actions) to run tests on my dev/staging/production environments?

### What I have done already

I have this test case:

```
import unittest
import os
import sqlalchemy

class Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_connection(self):
        """Check that we can connect to our database"""
        connexion_str = sqlalchemy.engine.URL.create(
                "mssql+pyodbc",
                username=os.environ["USERSQL"],
                password=os.environ["PWDSQL"],
                host=os.environ["SERVER"] + "," + os.environ["PORT"],
                database=os.environ["DATABASE"],
                query={"driver": "ODBC DRIVER 17 for SQL Server"},
            )
        connexion = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connexion_str)
        # Let's see if we have at least one table
        self.assertGreaterEqual(len(connexion.table_names()), 1)
```

Here is my Github workflow:

```
name: Tests
on: [push]
  
env:
  PYTHON_VERSION: '3.8'

jobs:
  Tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - uses: actions/setup-python@v2.2.2
      with:
        python-version: ${{ env.PYTHON_VERSION }}
    - run: python -m pip install -r my_project/requirements.txt
    - run: python -m unittest discover my_project "test_*.py" 
      env:
        SERVER: "${{ secrets.SERVER }}"
        USERSQL: "${{ secrets.USERSQL }}"
        PWDSQL: "${{ secrets.PWDSQL }}"
        PORT: "1433"
        DATABASE: "${{ secrets.DATABASE }}"
```

And in my Github settings I set the value of SERVER, USERSQL, PWDSQL, DATABASE to my "dev" database.

### My questions

1. How can I test the code on the **master** branch against my development database, the code on the **staging** branch against my staging database and the code on the **production** branch against my production database ?
2. Is it safe/wise to do so? Let's say someone in my team writes a "DELETE" query in the test suite, I don't think it should be sent to my production database.

Comment: Did you add the secrets as repository secrets or env secrets? Generally in my org we add secrets to the repository with a suffix for each env (e.g: SERVER_DEV, SERVER_PROD) and use them according to the branch, as you can filter it with github actions (another option is to create a workflow for each env with different triggers). However, as you said, if someone add a DELETE test, it will run in the specific env when the workflow will be executed, so you need to evaluate the pros/cons according to your context.

Comment: The secrets are set as repository secrets (I'm actually using Azure KeyVault but I wrote kind of a minimal reproducible example)

Comment: Would it be possible to add secrets for each ENV on Azure KeyVault? If yes, I believe it is the safest approach. Now, regarding the DELETE concern, I don't think you'll be able to check it through Github Actions, except if you have a kind of scan action to check if specific files contains the word DELETE or something like this.

Comment: Indeed for the secrets, using 3 differents KeyVaults would be nice, I can keep the same names for the environment variables, and just change the keyvault name. That does not solve the issue with the production database manipulation though

Comment: You can use a different trigger or workflow for each branch based on that. The master branch for dev db, staging branch for stg db and production branch for prod db. Each brqnch will trigger only the workflow related to its db.